# Rear hub is sticky and clacking when backpadeling

Tags: repair, nexus

I'm having trouble with my Nexus 8 Hub. It started to feel strange recently after a tour. I got help by someone in a free bicycle garage. We opened up the hub, gave it an oil bath and greased all the bearings.
However, something is still not quite right. When backpedaling in the gears 1-4 it's a bit sticky. So the wheel starts spinning backwards. The same is true for gears 5-8 but it also makes a clacking sound in those. I've uploaded some videos here: https://imgur.com/gallery/fyKyx9s

What could cause that? I don't believe we've broken anything while opening up the hub. Did we assemble it wrong? The cable seems to have the right tension, at least the two yellow things seem to align perfectly. Going through the gears is also fine. I have taken it out of the drop-out multiple times and checked for anything that looks strange, but I can't find anything.

I'm rather inexperienced but I want to get into self-servicing my bike. But I don't quite know what I'm doing yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If there is a "dork disk", have you checked that it's properly attached to the spokes and doesn't rub on the largest sprocket?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There is no dork disk installed.